# linear transformation $T: M_{5}(\mathbb{C}) \to M_{5}(\mathbb{C})$ that for any invertible matrix $A \in M_{5}(\mathbb{C})$,$rank(T(A))=4$

Tags: linear-algebra

> linear transformation $T: M_{5}(\mathbb{C}) \to M_{5}(\mathbb{C})$ that for any invertible matrix $A \in M_{5}(\mathbb{C})$,$rank(T(A))=4$,does T exist?

I guess no.here is some result I've proved:
consider dimension of Img(T(A))+Img(T(B)) for some invertible matrix A,B,then $Im(T(A))=Im(T(B))$ or $Img(T(A))+Img(T(B))=\mathbb{C}^5$

but i can go no further.

Comment: To be clear, you are interested in the rank of $T(A)$ not the rank of $T$, correct?  For the former, what if $T(A)=A \begin{bmatrix}  I_4 &\mathbf 0  \\  \mathbf 0 &  0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @user8675309 you are right. that's the example i want.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

For a linear transformation to be invertible it must be bijective. Since the rank of the transformation is $4$ the image of the transformation is four dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$. However since $M_5(\mathbb{C})$ has more than four dimensions such a bijection cannot exist. This is because the nullspace is non-zero (ie nullity is greater than zero), so $T$ cannot be injective and therefore not bijective.

Comment: It is the rank of $T(A)$ (a particular matrix in the image of $T$) rather than the rank of $T$ (the transformation over matrices) that is meant to be $4$.

Comment: This is not really relevant.